# Why create an interface for item clicks of the RecyclerView when you can do it inside ViewHolder of the RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Can you show me an example where it is more appropriate to use an interface to set clickListener of items in the RecyclerView. Look at this code.

```
class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.b1) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            // Call the call method here 
            // with position or data Object itself
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the button clickListener works fine, then why use an interface to set clicks of the items of RecyclerView?

```
private final MyClickListener mMyClickListener;

public MyAdapter(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    mMyClickListener = myClickListener;
}
```

Comment: what makes you think you don't use an interface there? Just because you use a different syntax, doesn't mean it's functionally different

Comment: `Why create an interface for item clicks` well, if you're looking at it like this then you're limiting yourself to just clicks, but if you create an interface to handle events from the adapter, then it makes more sense i think. what if your adapter needs to handle deletion, editing, tap, long press, etc

Comment: @a_local_nobody so you mean if I don't use an interface, there is a limit just for one action, whether it is deletion  or long press or tap etc.. but if I use interface I can handle different events, like deletion, long press, swipe and more. Is this what you mean?

Comment: you would be able to support multiple events without using an interface most likely, i'm just saying that using your own interface makes it (objectively) cleaner and easier

Comment: @a_local_nobody So just because it is cleaner and easier,  otherwise does not make any difference if I use interface or not. Correct? I have watched many videos, they say it is better to use an interface. But why? it is not much clear for me.

Comment: Ofcourse there is no need to propagate the click event to a fragment or activity from within onclick listener in cases where you can process every needed operation within the adapter scope. Unless you have to do some processing on object that cannot be reached within the adapter scope, or trigger one or more events that their access is beyond the adapter. Briefly it depends on case and need wether using an interface to the UI logic.

Comment: `otherwise does not make any difference if I use interface or not` well, you can test both to see if it works the same, if they both work then there's probably no functional difference, which means that people must have some other reason for doing it, right ? those reasons usually rely on experience and a better understanding of software development, stuff like unit testing, SOLID, clean code, etc.

Comment: in this case, using your own interface allows you to add in additional methods the adapter has to handle in future, where you currently don't have an easy and clean way of doing that, compared to the alternative